# Firebase Cloud Function for SSR Next.js App Not Finding Production Build in '/workspace/.next' Directory

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

I am trying to deploy a Next.js app with server-side rendering (SSR) using Firebase Functions and Google Cloud Functions. However, I keep encountering a deployment error that the production build directory /.next cannot be found. Here's the error message I'm seeing:

**nextServer Error: Could not find a production build in the '/workspace/.next' directory.**

[image]

functions/index.js

```
const next = require("next");
const express = require("express");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const nextApp = next({
  dev,
  // The path to the .next directory from the perspective of the functions/index.js file
  conf: { distDir: "../.next" },
});

const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();
const server = express();

server.get("*", (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res);
});

exports.nextServer = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log("File: " + req.originalUrl); // Useful for debugging
  return nextApp.prepare().then(() => server(req, res));
});
```

functions/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.6.0",
    "next": "13.4.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "gcp-build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only hosting:liberameappblog,functions"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "next": "^13.4.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "src/public", 
   "target": "liberameappblog",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextServer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/blog",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
  // ... any other configurations you have
};
```

my folder structure:

[image]

**My deployment process:**
I run next build (gcp-build) at the project root to generate the .next directory, and then I deploy using firebase deploy.

Despite the build apparently succeeding and the .next directory being present in my local environment, the deployed Cloud Function can't seem to find the build directory.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Firebase Functions and Next.js, or does anyone see where my configuration might be going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!