# How to resolve Firebase Cloud Function not locating the Next.js production build in '/workspace/.next' for SSR?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have previously asked this question and am still struggling with this issue; could anybody help me solve this problem:

[Firebase Cloud Function for SSR Next.js App Not Finding Production Build in '/workspace/.next' Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787761/firebase-cloud-function-for-ssr-next-js-app-not-finding-production-build-in-wo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are steps to troubleshoot and resolve the issue of a Firebase Cloud Function not locating the Next.js production build in '/workspace/.next' for SSR:**

**1. Verify Production Build Deployment:**

- Ensure you've run `next build` to create the production build.
- Double-check that the `.next` directory is present in your Firebase project's `functions` directory after deployment.

**2. Check Function Configuration:**

- Make sure your Firebase function correctly imports the Next.js app:

  ```js
  const { createServer } = require('http');
  const next = require('next');

  const app = next({ dev: false });
  const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

  exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     createServer(handle).listen(req, res);
  });
  ```
- If using a custom function entry point, ensure it points to the correct file path.

**3. Handle Build Output Directory:**

- If your build output directory differs from `.next`, specify it in the function configuration:

  ```js
  app.prepare().then(() => {
     createServer(handle).listen(req, res, {
       root: '/path/to/build/output'
     });
  });
  ```

**4. Clear Cache and Retry:**

- Clear Firebase CLI cache: `firebase functions:clear`
- Redeploy the function: `firebase deploy --only functions`

**5. Inspect Function Logs:**

- Check Firebase function logs for detailed errors or insights.

**Additional Considerations:**

- **Firebase CLI Version:** Use a compatible version (12.1.0 or later).
- **Framework-Aware Hosting:** If using, ensure proper configuration.
- **Experimental Features:** Be mindful of potential issues with experimental features.
- **Custom Build Configuration:** Adjust file paths accordingly if using custom build configurations.

**If the issue persists, provide more details about your setup for further troubleshooting:**

- Firebase CLI version
- Deployment commands
- Function configuration
- Custom build settings
- Relevant error messages